# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module commons.io not found, required by com.example.myapp

Tags: java, javafx, gradle

Всё работало.
Теперь почему-то не находит commons.io хотя он присутствует.

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module commons.io not found, required by com.example.myapp

Execution failed for task ':HelloApplication.main()'.

> Process 'command 'C:/Users/Alex/.jdks/openjdk-16.0.1/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.7.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = '16'
targetCompatibility = '16'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.example.myapp'
    mainClass = 'com.example.myapp.HelloApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '16'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.2'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:20030203.000550'
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.27")

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven Repository показывает, что последняя версия [Apache Commons IO - 2.11.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'
}
```

или

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.11.0'
}
```

Comment: Попробовал поменять, но не помогло.

Comment: Маловато информации.  Пробовали `gradle clean build`?

Comment: Нет, а как это сделать? Я только кэш чистил. Я ещё не особо разбираюсь, первый раз с ним работаю.